# Matrix of a linear operator on row vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm self-studying abstract algebra right now, and there's a exercise in the textbook about the matrix of a linear transformation as follows:

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let $V$ denote the space of $n$-dimensional *row* vectors. What is the matrix of the linear operator "right multiplication by $A$" with respect to the standard basis of $V$?

As far as I can tell, since the linear transformation starts and ends with the same vector space, its matrix should just be $A$, but I'm a little suspicious, since this answer is so simple and "easy to think of" compared to other questions in the textbook. Have I gotten something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I think you're right.  But can you prove it?

Comment: That would be correct for left multiplication, that is, $v$ gets sent to $Av$ But right multiplication means that $v$ gets sent to $vA$. Think transpose.